# How to create scatter plot in MS Excel with non digit column?

Tags: plot, excel-2007, scatter-plot

I have two columns in excel, one is date (X) and another one is some text (Y). May I know how can I create the scatter plot in MS Excel with these data? Thanks.

```
Date (X)        Category (Y)
01/04/2012 00   Middleware
01/10/2012 09   End User
01/11/2012 02   End User
01/11/2012 15   Middleware
01/26/2012 03   End User
02/15/2012 09   End User
02/16/2012 07   End User
02/20/2012 10   Middleware
03/17/2012 01   OS
03/20/2012 01   Middleware
03/23/2012 11   Middleware
04/09/2012 07   Middleware
04/26/2012 06   Middleware
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to plot numerical values in a chart. Are you just showing a timeline with markers at a particular height for a particular category? In this case, insert a column with arbitrary numerical values for the category (e.g., 1=OS, 2=Middleware, 3=End User). Plot this as the Y against the times for X. Use text boxes cover the 1, 2, 3 on the Y axis with Labels showing the categories.